# Azure VM End point unreachable

Tags: azure

Below is my scenario. I have created an Azure VM endpoint. This endpoint is configured to listen on port xxx. The same port number is configured as both public and private port (on the endpoint). This port number within the VM is actually a port that SQL Server endpoint is linked to.

Then I have added an ACL to allow traffic only from a specific public IP. i.e our office public IP.

Now I am trying to connect to SQL Server remotely through this new port and I am not able to. Locally on the VM this SQL Server port is functioning as it supposed to.

[image: CLick here for a picture which is the endpoint configuration. Should give some context.]

Comment: Have you verified that SQL Server is running properly on your vm? Have you connected to it from your vm (localhost connection)?

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes, have tested it locally and the SQL Server itself is working fine. The main issue is connectivity over the internet to that specific VM end point.